# CSS bug on Safari only

Tags: html, css, safari

I have assembled the draft of a portfolio page to be the starting point to build it. Everything works well on Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, the top navbar leans to the right (screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqW7q.png). The behaviour I would like to have is to have the nav menu to be displayed without any spaces to the sides, like it does on Chrome or Firefox

Inspecting the elements, the most likely selector to change it is one called `items-container`, but tweaking is values do not solve the question. Scrolling to see the inheritances lead to another selector, `nav-items`. However, if any change is done there, the display in the other browsers is affected.

I am not a CSS expert, but I usually manage to set up things properly, but I don't know what can be the problem (which should be a Safari one), let alone fix it in a way that works the same way in any browser. I created a Codepen with the source code (https://codepen.io/gobbet/pen/PoqYvbr) and would like to ask for insights for the problem (which I presume that should be somehow straightforward). Thanks to all in advance for the availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `left: 0;` to `.items-container`

Not all browsers position absolute elements at 0 0 of the parent element

Comment: Thanks for both Matan and Prowner! Question solved! Had to flag one of the answers as the correct, so I set prowner's because it was written a minute before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in Safari, the default for `left` is not 0.

```
.items-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; /* <- */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```